# VB6: Is there a standard library (parser) to strip HTML tags from content?

Tags: vb6, html-parsing

I am looking for a standard/decent library/parser to strip HTML tags from content. Here's the kicker...I need it to be in VB6 (legacy project).

Anyone have any suggestions?